# Time format conversion

Tags: php, date, datetime, time, timezone

I need to convert a specific date format into local time (Europe/Sarajevo), I have the time in this format 2013-02-17T15:00:00Z which I don't really understand and this is why I don't know how to convert it to the Europe/Sarajevo time, who knows maybe it is already Sarajevo time, I don't know...

OK I can parse it and remove the T and Z and get a time but these letters mean something, probably they affect the result time...

The result time is for example 2013-02-17 18:00:00, probably there will be a difference due to the letters T and Z which are probably time offset.

Comment: That is [ISO8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format, which is one of a few different standards for date/time formats.  It is slowly becoming the defacto standard on the web - although there are still others out there like RFC1123.  You can read about these [here](http://www.hackcraft.net/web/datetime/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use DateTime. It's much better for working with timezones:

```
$datetime = new DateTime('2013-02-17T15:00:00Z');
$datetime->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/Sarajevo'));
echo $datetime->format('c');
```

**Reference**

- [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)
- [DateTimeZone](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetimezone.php)

[See it in action](http://codepad.viper-7.com/SlQPgm)

Answer (score 1):

You can use php date function like this

```
 $date = '2013-02-17T15:00:00Z';
 echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($date));
```

See the [Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)